# Scroll fixed header with content

Tags: html, css

I have a task that I can't solve.

I have a web content, which contains a header div, content div and a full image in background. The header div has a fixed position and I can't change it.

The point is, I have to write the css, which will allow me to scroll header up with content. Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/AKL35/249/).

What I want is to scroll header with content, but keep header div position fixed.

```
body {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

div.sidebar {
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 580px;
}
div#fixed {
    background: #76a7dc;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    width: 580px;  
    height:50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Like facebook where the header is fixed at the top of the page?

Comment: no in facebook, the header is fixed, and not scrolling

Comment: is this what you are looking for? - http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/AKL35/246/

Comment: no, i want to scroll header with content, but keep the heder position fixed; try yourself, change                                            div#fixed {
    background: #76a7dc;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}                                                                             to                                                                           div#fixed {
    background: #76a7dc;
    padding-bottom: 10px;                                             position:fixed;
    color: #fff;
}

Answer (score 0):

So currently you have it set up where the header is fixed and does not scroll with the content.

If I am reading what you wrote correctly, this header already has the css properties of position: fixed and you cannot change that, right?

To make it scroll with the content, you would put the       overflow-y: scroll; on the sidebar container then instead of the .scrollable container.

Comment: oh, no wait, it is actually doesn't work, i forgot to put the position:fixed; for header above  http://jsfiddle.net/AKL35/6/